# feature matrices in pst-asr

Tags: matrices, amsart, pst-asr

I need feature matrices within my `pst-asr` phonological structure. The [manual](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6kd__j_DRAhXElFQKHR5ZDycQFggkMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ctan.org%2Ftex-archive%2Fgraphics%2Fpstricks%2Fcontrib%2Fpst-asr&usg=AFQjCNHKYPuhpdxQMAGk5TI21C_ziu8DSQ&sig2=KIUcDcfAP-Em865Pu4ruWg), p.15, proposes the following macro:

```
\def\\#1#2{$\left[\matrix
     {\rm #1cons\hfill\cr \rm#2sonor\cr}\right]$}
```

However, I can't make it work. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{pst-asr}
\def\feat#1{$\rm [#1]$}
\def\\#1#2{$\left[\matrix{\rm #1cons\hfill\cr \rm#2son\cr}\right]$}
\tiershortcuts

\begin{document}

\newtier{obstr}
\psset{xgap=1.5in, yunit=2em, phB=-1, ts=0 (Pg),
  obstr=-1 ([), tssym=$\times$}
\DefList{\cont{-0.5}, \obstr{0}, \cons{1}, \voi{1}}

 \asr \X |
 \@(\obstr,obstr){\\+-}
    \-(0,ts)
 \endasr

\end{document}
```

Changing the `\documentclass` from `amsart` to `article` would make it work, but I was interested to ask if anybody knows the reason why `amsart` does not like matrices, and if there is a solution for it.

Comment: i'm not in a position to test this now (i can do that tomorrow, when i'm at a real computer), but i suspect two reasons: (1) `amsmath` has defined a number of matrix structures as environments, so `\matrix` has been effectively disabled, and (2) redefining `\\ ` is not a great idea when it is so heavily used by `amsmath` to split lines of multi-line displays.  since `amsmath` is automatically loaded by `amsart`, this makes for a very shaky situation.

Comment: Interesting. I also tried to use `\begin{matrix} ... \end{matrix}` instead of `\matrix{ }`, but it won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason this doesn't work with `amsart` is mainly because `amsart` automatically
loads `amsmath`, which redefines `\matrix` as an environment.  (several environments,
actually.)  also, redefining `\\` which is used for *many* things related to
starting a new line isn't a good idea.

but the following reformulation seems to work -- it produces output identical to
that when `article` is used -- although the version of tex live (2016)
i have available has a problem when running pdflatex.  (it finds that
`\c@lor@to@ps` is an undefined control sequence.  but that's a different
kettle of fish, and should be reported as something that needs updating.
all works just fine with "ordinary" latex-to-dvi.)

there is certainly a better choice of name than `\9` for what i chose to replace
`\\` but that's up to you.  since `amsart` has a matrix environment that already
includes properly sized brackets, i used that instead of the `\left[ ... \right]` formulation.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{pst-asr}
\def\feat#1{$\rm [#1]$}
%\def\\#1#2{$\left[\matrix{\rm #1cons\hfill\cr \rm#2son\cr}\right]$}
\def\9#1#2{$\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathrm{#1cons}\\ \mathrm{#2son}
  \end{bmatrix}$}
\tiershortcuts

\begin{document}

\newtier{obstr}
\psset{xgap=1.5in, yunit=2em, phB=-1, ts=0 (Pg),
  obstr=-1 ([), tssym=$\times$}
\DefList{\cont{-0.5}, \obstr{0}, \cons{1}, \voi{1}}

 \asr \X |
% \@(\obstr,obstr){\\+-}
 \@(\obstr,obstr){\9+-}
    \-(0,ts)
 \endasr

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]